# Automatically `pull` when there is what to pull to my repo: `post-merge` git server hook using PHP

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, githooks

**What I want to accomplish:**

I have juts installed git on my development server. 
I create a branch out of my 'develop' branch, work on my new feature branch, commit, and when I'm done - I merge the new feature branch with the 'develop' branch.

To apply the changes for the 'develop' branch on my development server I have to log in to my server and use `git pull` - which I'm trying to prevent and happen automatically - when there is something to pull from my development server - it will be done automatically.

I hope I'm clear about that I'm trying to accomplish ;)

**What I have done up till now is:**

1. Created a folder inside my project `/www/hooks/` and added a file called `post-merge`: Following [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge) - this should get triggered whenever I merge a branch.
2. Inside this folder I added the text:

   [image]

which should execute whatever is in between the backticks symbol ( ` ) as a shell command [(following this PHP documentation)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

3. Inside the folder `/www/.git/hooks/` I added a symbolic-link to the file I previously mentioned with the same exact name: `/www/hooks/post-merge` :

> ```
> sudo ln -s -f /www/hooks/post-merge /www/.git/hooks/post-merge
> ```

4. I gave the linked file under `/www/.git/hooks/post-merge` 775 file permission as the other files.

**Some notes:**

- My repo is on Bitbucket
- My directory `/www/homepage/` is the one with the index file, so nothing can run outside of it on a browser (apache2 points to it..) - (but i guess there shouldn't be a problem since it's self executed via `/.git/hooks` ?)
- I tried renaming both my files (the one under `/www/.git/hooks/` & `/www/hooks/`) to `post-merge.php` and this didn't work.

Comment: change your image link by real text pls, my proxy don't like imgur

Comment: @MacBooc it uses backticks so it doesn't show up on stackoverflow :( 
its_____ <?php `git pull`;

Comment: while it's shell script did you try to add `#!/usr/bin/php` before the begin of your open tag of php ?

Comment: <?php #!/usr/bin/php 'git pull'; ?> 
like this? ( ' = ` )

Comment: I mainly followedthis tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh--net-19564
which doesn't mention anything like this.

without the "Post-Receive URL" part (followed a manual tutorial instead since bitbucket doesn't work the same as github in these cases https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sBXEQ1dN4A ) @MacBooc

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/php <?php 'git pull'; ?>` more like this, it just suggestion i can't try it at the moment, i'll take a look on it later, where `usr/bin/php` is the path of your php

Comment: also are you able to pull your git repository in a classic php script ? https://jondavidjohn.com/git-pull-from-a-php-script-not-so-simple/

Comment: Will never work outside `/www/homepage` I'll only be able to test it tomorrow

Comment: but if you can't reach php, you won't be able to do it in php, at least i can't figure out how it could work, or maybe by make an http request in shell script to your website on a specific url which doing this gitpull... by the way why do you want to do it in php ?

Comment: I have just tested - does't work when running post-merge.php this from  a browser

Comment: @MacBooc So from my logic, if it's triggered by the server - so the server should know to self execute the file (or am i wrong) as long that its triggered from within and not externally via a browser for exampel

Comment: I'm just used to write in PHP, much more familiar to me and for the others developers around me. 
What do you recommend? a simple bash?

Comment: `post-merge.php` my `#!/usr/bin/php` could work in a `post-merge` without extension php. One co-worker did something like this, i'll check it later to you how he did it, but yeah using bash i guess

Comment: @MacBooc waiting for your reply :D

Comment: we did something like that `#!/bin/bash
git --git-dir "path/master/.git" --work-tree "path/master" pull origin master` you could try this in your post-merge

Answer (score 0):

just to have Carriage return

```
#!/bin/bash 
git --git-dir "path/master/.git" --work-tree "path/master" pull origin master
```

you could try this in your post-merge